# Max database name length in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I am trying to do some UI validation on a database name. I was told from different places that the SQL Server database name is stored as [sysname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240.aspx) inside SQL Server. I also verified that by checking the [sys.Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx).

So, I make my textbox in the UI to have maxlength 128 characters long.  This is the max length of `sysname` type.

However, I found that in my SQL Server 2005 Express edition, if I enter a database name with 128 characters long, it always complains

> Could not create default log file because the name was too long

To make sure I can successfully create the database, I found that I need to set the max limit to 124 characters.

My question now is whether 124 characters limit is true for all versions of SQL Server on all different Windows OS?

Comment: Possibly useful info: [Windows Maximum Path Length Limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath)

Comment: You can create a log file of any name in the `CREATE ` database statement. It doesn't have to contain the DB name...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The log file name does not need to include the database name.

This works fine for me for example.

```
CREATE DATABASE [AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA] ON  PRIMARY 
( 
NAME = N'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\A128.mdf')
 LOG ON 
( 
NAME = N'A128_log', 
FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\A128_log.LDF')
```

Comment: I see.  I think I understand the problem now.  There are two limits - one for database name and one for the log file.  I think you are right that it's because if I don't specify the log file name, it automatically append "_log" to my database name as my log file name.  That makes my maximum limit 124.

Answer (score 6):

Are you not running into the problem of the file names for the data and log files. The underlying operating system (Windows) places restrictions on it and therefore the database cannot be created. The database name may be 128 characters long and works given that the file names used are not being to long (when using the SQL Server Management Studio it automatically generates file names based on the database names, and they therefore end up being long).