# Invalid database name specified for backup or restore operation in when database path is long in localdb 2012

Tags: c#, entity-framework, localdb

I'm using sql server localdb v11.0 with EF.
I use the following code to backup:

```
public void BackupDatabase(string filePath, string DbPath)
{
    using (CameraManDBEntities dbEntities = new CameraManDBEntities())
    {
        string backupQuery = @"BACKUP DATABASE @DbPath TO DISK = N'{0}'";
        backupQuery = string.Format(backupQuery, filePath);

        dbEntities.Database.SqlQuery<object>(backupQuery, new SqlParameter("DbPath", DbPath)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

When I call the following method:

```
BackupDatabase(BackUpFileName, @"C:\Users\Mahmood\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZV0DG5JM.3OH\XQ31WEZB.OKA\camman.exe_af50f6b9afda55f2_0001.0005_none_2c544a12b9bb2c09" + "\\CameraManDB.mdf");
```

It throws this exception:

```
Invalid database name 'C:\Users\Mahmood\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\ZV0DG5JM.3OH\XQ31WEZB.OKA\camman.exe_af50f6b9afda55f2_0001.0005_none_2c544a12b9bb2c09\CameraManDB.mdf' specified for backup or restore operation.\r\nBACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

When I use a short path for database name parameter like "E:\PROGRAMMING\CAMMAN\CAMMAN\BIN\RELEASE\CAMERAMANDB.MDF", It works fine.

Comment: Something is wrong in your parameters? Did you invert the order?

Comment: I did but it throws a new exception: database doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you have in your connection string? The first parameter to BACKUP DATABASE is the logical name of the database (not the MDF file name) and the second parameter is the name of the file that will contain your backup: Something like `BACKUP DATABASE  MyCustomers TO DISK = N'C:\BACKUPS\MyCustomer-2015-02-16,bak`

Comment: Here is my connection string section in app.config file:  `<add name="CameraManDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CamDBModel.csdl|res://*/CamDBModel.ssdl|res://*/CamDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\CameraManDB.mdf;integrated security=True;Connect Timeout=60;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Comment: Are you sure that the backup with shorter path actually worked out? Or did it just complete without the mentioned error? Because the main error cause would be, that your long path is 141 characters in length, where you are actually allowed to have up to 128 characters ([still, you need to know your limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096125/max-database-name-length-in-sql-server))