# Cannot open database "MyDb" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'My-PC\\MrD'

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I have been connecting to my local database (SQL Express) fine all day from my C# console application.

I have made an update, where I create a database and table from within the C# code using ADO.NET

When I do this, my normal connection string fails, which is

```
    Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;  Trusted_Connection=True;  Initial Catalog=ThisIsMyDataBase;
```

The error message is

```
Cannot open database "ThisIsMyDataBase" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'My-PC\\MrD'.
```

If I open the tables in SSMS, then I can access everything, using Windows Authentication.

I was under the impression that the `Trusted_Connection=True` would mean I have permission, and that I'm accessing it with my Windows account (not an SQL account) would mean I don't see this issue, but I'm clearly wrong. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: please post your entire connection string..

Comment: That **is** the entire connection string @Sachu, and it's been working fine (when the database was created in SSMS), but with this update (where the database is created via my application) it no longer works...

Comment: Does your windows user actually have permission to look at the database?

Comment: @Mathew, I can only assume so, I have no problem accessing the data from within SSMS

Comment: please try to login using the user mentioned through sql server

Comment: @Sachu, updated my post, it works fine if I log on via SSMS using Windows Autehntication

Comment: just give `User Instance=True' and try..don't think its needed but just give a try

Comment: @Sachu, thanks for staying with me, but sadly, this didn't make a difference

Comment: try this 'Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on My-PC\MrD' and select Properties . Then select 'user mapping' on the left pane. Select the database Mydb then in database role at the botton tick dbowner and check the connection..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77706/discussion-between-sachu-and-mydaftquestions).

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions use below string `@"Server=localhost; Database= MyDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;";`

Answer (score 0):

You propably do not have the sql server login, which is associated with your WIN user, mapped to a database user.

Check that your model database (under System databases in management studio) has your WIN user listed under Security/Users. If not, add it. Then delete the MyDb database and create it again using you code. The CREATE DATABASE statement uses a copy of the model database to create the new database and its metadata.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions, I updated my answer based on your create script

Comment: I don't see it here, but, I don't see the My-PC\MrD in any of the other databases and I can access them fine

Comment: Ok, check the Server Roles of your WIN user under Security / Logins / right click on My-PC\MrD and select properties. If the sysadmin is selected, you have implicit access to all of the databases for that login.

Comment: If you are using an OLE DB provider you should use `Integrated Security=SSPI;` instead of `Trusted_Connection=True;` in your connection string.

Comment: And the data source should be like: `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` with only one `\\`.

Comment: Sorry, it's \\ because it's C# code.. I can't have a single, it'll act as an escape character

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions, you should use [string literals](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-literal) for connection strings.
And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096125/max-database-name-length-in-sql-server) might explain your problem with the long database name.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is saying the user dont have access `failed for user 'My-PC\\MrD'.` do a login for the user from sql server itself

Comment: Logging in via SSMS has no problem. However, I would like to be able to query my database from my console application!

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution but I don't understand it at all

The answer is to rename the database with less characters. My actual database was 27 characters long, I've just given it a 4 character long name (simply called My01) and it works fine.